# What is naming convention for a file with Kotlin extensions?

Tags: kotlin, naming-conventions, naming, kotlin-extension

I have generated class `MyDto` and I want to add couple of new functions

```
fun MyDto.convert(foo: String): Bar {...
```

I have no choice - I have to put it to different file but in contrast to java it won't be a class but just a Kotlin file.

How should I call it ?

`MyDtoUtils.kt` or `myDtoUtils.kt` ?

Is there any convention for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the [Coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names) from kotlinlang.org

> If a file contains multiple classes, or only top-level declarations,
> choose a name describing what the file contains, and name the file
> accordingly. Use an upper camel case with an uppercase first letter
> (also known as Pascal case), for example, ProcessDeclarations.kt.

So from that, I think you should go with `MyDtoUtils.kt`

Comment: The same link also says "avoid using meaningless words such as `Util` in file names."